# Play Store - Item not found

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

**Problem Statement:**

I published App on **Google Play** but can't see it there - instead it shows error message saying that **Item Not Found**.

**Summary:**

I published an App on **Play Store**. Its current status is **Published** as can be seen from following snapshot.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=171vhJJ5ED_g1v2ElD5xBwdRAcrW0RoNF

When i tap on **VIEW ON GOOGLE PLAY**, I can see it there as well with **Published** status.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=16Zy7GXhreeSdli7IBrhFBvwNP51m8HTm

Problem is, when i tap **VIEW ON GOOGLE PLAY** in Android Phone, i can't see there any App and see following

https://drive.google.com/open?id=12Pa7ITr93OlQJQV5UXbJfNYI8fEG66LR

Although App is allowed in **ALL** countries, but still i can't see it in **Play Store**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you're having is when you search Google Play Store for your app's name, your app doesn't come up although, but you can download it if you had the app's direct link in the Play Store and even shows published on your developer portal.

Publishing an app to the Google Play Store doesn't have a fixed/specific time before it becomes downloadable (**search and download**) from the Play Store. Sometimes, it takes few hours while other times it could take days. This is because it is being deployed to all the Google Play servers worldwide. Mine takes about 2-3 days sometimes. Just be patient and wait for some time.

Comment: its gonna around 8 days i published app

Answer (score 0):

If the status of an app is **PUBLISHED**, then it is actually published.

The answer to your question lies in the nature of the algorithm the Google Play store uses for their search/query. You probably used a common app name (or the variant of a common app name). Generally, apps with a large number of active users top the list in search results. Your app is on the list, it's just at the bottom of the list.

[This article](https://www.adweek.com/digital/google-discloses-how-search-for-google-play-works-for-the-first-time-12-percent-of-dau-search-for-apps-daily/) sheds a little light on how the search algorithms work and what you should always look out to ensure your app's immediate visibility.

I hope this helps. Merry coding!